# FFmpeg command-line on Android

Tags: android, video, command-line, ffmpeg, format

I´m trying to use this ffmpeg command line on Android:

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/DCIM/video.mp4 -s 480x320 /sdcard/output.mp4
```

I have the executable file of ffmpeg (on this path: /data/local/tmp/ffmpeg/ with chmod 751), and as I read, I´m trying to invoke it using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/local/tmp/ffmpeg -i /sdcard/DCIM/video.mp4 -s 480x320 /sdcard/output.mp4");
```

But I´m not getting any result after this calling, so I tried the same command but using the android terminal and I´m sure ffmpeg works because I ´m getting many outputs like video data. But it doesn´t do the action I want, I´m getting this message:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '/sdcard/output.mp4'
```

I don´t have any idea about what it can be the issue...
Thanks for help!!

Comment: It's not clear: do you get the job done when you run `/data/local/tmp/ffmpeg` from adb shell or terminal emulator, or the file is still not there? What is written to console?

Comment: I´m sorry... When I invoke the command, using the adb shell, terminal emulator or directly from my app, I don´t get the file converted (My ffmpeg command should convert a video and export it). I know the ffmpeg binary/executable file works because some video data is written to console, but I don´t get the output video file because the error I said (Unable to find a suitable output format)

Comment: What exactly do you get on the console? Maybe, your ffmpeg has not been configured for mp4 output?

Answer (score 1):

It probably shouldn't work because ffmpeg will refer to /usr/lib where will look for installed libs. But this is android this approach won't work.

Probably you should compile ffmpeg into a single library like libffmpeg.so and write c - wrapper, which will load it from your app location like /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libffmpeg.so and pass params to this library.

So: You will load your wrapper through jni and pass ffmpeg params then wrapper will load actual ffmpeg and pass params to it.

I have tried this in one project, it works

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I have been trying this way because I think it´s easier. I know the way you are refering, but I don´t think I´m able to write the C file to invoke the command I want. What should I do to solve my issue using the executable file?? Because, I don´t know how to invoke the commands I want using the JNI and the C file (the way you say)... I don´t mind which way to use but I don´t know how to invoke my command with your way...

Comment: ffmpeg" will refer to /usr/lib where will look for installed libs" - only if built as *shared*. It cannot be the case, though: launch of the executable would have failed miserably.

Comment: Hi, @AlexCohn, I´m sure I have the libs installed because I was trying a command and I got the audio extracted of a video file . But I don´t know why my command fails when I want to convert a video file... Any idea?? Could it be something related with the output codec?

Comment: can you pass -v flag to ffmpeg print verbose logs? If it will run, it will print version and some another information. That way you will sure if it runs at all. If ffmpeg will find some error it should print it in verbose mode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to resize video?

I've installed [ffmpeg](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silentlexx.ffmpeggui&hl=en_AU&gl=US) on my Android.

Then after install, I open app via CLI:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/WTFMan.mp4" -b:v 1.4M -vf scale=480:320  "/storage/emulated/0/FFMPEG/SickMan.mp4"
```

and at the end I get a message saying "Complete"

Tested on Android 10

Comment: I installed that app, but I still don't have ffmpeg from adb shell .. how are you getting that? Thanks! @Zimba

Comment: The program u installed has android gui. There is button at bottom right swithes to console.   You can write ffmeg command in that textbox.  Press execute button.

Comment: What cli client Did you used?